# Speed-efficient classification in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I have an image of size as RGB `uint8(576,720,3)` where I want to classify each pixel to a set of colors. I have transformed using `rgb2lab` from RGB to LAB space, and then removed the L layer so it is now a `double(576,720,2)` consisting of AB.

Now, I want to classify this to some colors that I have trained on another image, and calculated their respective AB-representations as:

```
Cluster 1: -17.7903  -13.1170
Cluster 2: -30.1957   40.3520
Cluster 3:  -4.4608   47.2543
Cluster 4:  46.3738   36.5225
Cluster 5:  43.3134  -17.6443
Cluster 6:  -0.9003    1.4042
Cluster 7:   7.3884   11.5584
```

Now, in order to classify/label each pixel to a cluster 1-7, I currently do the following (pseudo-code):

```
clusters;
for each x
  for each y
    ab = im(x,y,2:3);
    dist = norm(ab - clusters); // norm of dist between ab and each cluster
    [~, idx] = min(dist);
  end
end
```

However, this is terribly slow (52 seconds) because of the image resolution and that I manually loop through each x and y.

Are there some built-in functions I can use that performs the same job? There must be.

To summarize: **I need a classification method that classifies pixel images to an already defined set of clusters.**

Comment: Any runtime comparison on how well the accepted solution works against the actual code for the pseudo one that you had posted, if  you did code it?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, and it was actually quite interesting.

My first attempt: 52 seconds.
My first attempt, but migrated to use parallel computing (4 pools): 10 seconds.
Approach #1: 0.06 seconds.
Quite amazing.

Comment: And with approach #2, have you had a chance to try out that too? Sorry to be noisy about these figures, but these kinda get me excited :)

Comment: Hehe, it's cool :) I really enjoy the fact that matrix programming even outperforms parallel computing by that much! Is there any limit as to how big matrixes can be in order to stay in the memory?

I haven't tried Approach #2 yet, but I can do it later today to check it out.

Comment: Well with approach #1, you would get to the memory bandwidth limit soon, but with approach #2, it should hold better with large datasizes. I would be keen to know about runtime comparisons for approach #2, specially for large datasizes, if you would like to test out, let me know! By the way that great speedup magic with the matrix programming which we call as the vectorization had a big player in `bsxfun`, the most versatile tool for vectorization!

Comment: @Divakar Approach #1 ranges from 0.06-0.09 seconds whereas Approach #2 ranges from 0.04-0.06 seconds. So it's a wee bit faster.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for getting those numbers! Kool!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Approach #1

For a `N x 2` sized points/pixels array, you can avoid `permute` as suggested in the [other solution by Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26994433/3293881), which could slow down things a bit, to have a kind of `"permute-unrolled"` version of it and also let's `bsxfun` work towards a `2D` array instead of a `3D` array, which must be better with performance.

Thus, assuming clusters to be ordered as a `N x 2` sized array, you may try this other `bsxfun` based approach -

```
%// Get a's and b's
im_a = im(:,:,2);
im_b = im(:,:,3);

%// Get the minimum indices that correspond to the cluster IDs
[~,idx]  = min(bsxfun(@minus,im_a(:),clusters(:,1).').^2 + ...
    bsxfun(@minus,im_b(:),clusters(:,2).').^2,[],2);
idx = reshape(idx,size(im,1),[]);
```

---

## Approach #2

You can try out another approach that leverages  [**`fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) and is based on [this smart solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23911671/3293881) -

```
d = 2; %// dimension of the problem size

im23 = reshape(im(:,:,2:3),[],2);

numA = size(im23,1);
numB = size(clusters,1);

A_ext = zeros(numA,3*d);
B_ext = zeros(numB,3*d);
for id = 1:d
    A_ext(:,3*id-2:3*id) = [ones(numA,1), -2*im23(:,id), im23(:,id).^2 ];
    B_ext(:,3*id-2:3*id) = [clusters(:,id).^2 ,  clusters(:,id), ones(numB,1)];
end
[~, idx] = min(A_ext * B_ext',[],2); %//'
idx = reshape(idx, size(im,1),[]); %// Desired IDs
```

### What’s going on with the matrix multiplication based distance matrix calculation?

Let us consider two matrices `A` and `B` between whom we want to calculate the distance matrix. For the sake of an easier explanation that follows next, let us consider `A` as `3 x 2` and `B` as `4 x 2` sized arrays, thus indicating that we are working with X-Y points. If we had `A` as `N x 3` and `B` as `M x 3` sized arrays, then those would be `X-Y-Z` points.

Now, if we have to manually calculate the first element of the square of distance matrix, it would look like this –

```
first_element = ( A(1,1) – B(1,1) )^2 + ( A(1,2) – B(1,2) )^2
```

which would be –

```
first_element = A(1,1)^2 + B(1,1)^2 -2*A(1,1)* B(1,1)   +  ...
                A(1,2)^2 + B(1,2)^2 -2*A(1,2)* B(1,2)    … Equation  (1)
```

Now, according to our proposed matrix multiplication, if you check the output of `A_ext` and `B_ext` after the loop in the earlier code ends, they would look like the following –

[image]

[image]

So, if you perform matrix multiplication between `A_ext` and transpose of `B_ext`, the first element of the product would be the sum of elementwise multiplication between the first rows of `A_ext` and `B_ext`, i.e. sum of these –

[image]

The result would be identical to the result obtained from `Equation (1)` earlier. This would continue for all the elements of `A` against all the elements of `B` that are in the same column as in `A`.  Thus, we would end up with the complete squared distance matrix. That’s all there is!!

### Vectorized Variations

Vectorized variations of the matrix multiplication based distance matrix calculations are possible, though there weren't any big performance improvements seen with them. Two such variations are listed next.

**Variation #1**

```
[nA,dim] = size(A);
nB = size(B,1);

A_ext = ones(nA,dim*3);
A_ext(:,2:3:end) = -2*A;
A_ext(:,3:3:end) = A.^2;

B_ext = ones(nB,dim*3);
B_ext(:,1:3:end) = B.^2;
B_ext(:,2:3:end) = B;

distmat = A_ext * B_ext.';
```

**Variation #2**

```
[nA,dim] = size(A);
nB = size(B,1);

A_ext = [ones(nA*dim,1) -2*A(:) A(:).^2];
B_ext = [B(:).^2 B(:) ones(nB*dim,1)];

A_ext = reshape(permute(reshape(A_ext,nA,dim,[]),[1 3 2]),nA,[]);
B_ext = reshape(permute(reshape(B_ext,nB,dim,[]),[1 3 2]),nB,[]);

distmat = A_ext * B_ext.';
```

So, these could be considered as experimental versions too.

Comment: Apologies but my Linear Algebra is a bit rusty. I wish you would create a detailed explanation of the smart solution because you keep posting it and I don't get it completely.  Especially `HelpA`, `HelpB` and `helpA * helpB'`. Why do you do `ones(numA,1)`? Why do you use `-2` in `-2*im23(:,id)`? Why do you create the the values of  `helpA` and `HelpB` in that order? What is the purpose of `helpA * helpB'`?

Comment: @kkuilla See if the explanation in the edits make sense?

Comment: @Divakar Good improvement on `bsxfun`, and very thorough answer! +1

Comment: Oh, yes. Fantastic. Thank you. +50 :-). I didn't see that you re-wrote `(A(1,1)-B(1,1))^2 +((A(1,2)-B(1,2)^2)` using that rule I can't remember the name of. Excellent explanation.

Comment: @kkuilla Funny thing even I forgot the name to it, elementary school's been long gone, but I think it could be named as expansion of square of subtraction maybe :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics Toolbox) to compute the distances in a vectorized manner:

```
ab = im(:,:,2:3);                              % // get A, B components
ab = reshape(ab, [size(im,1)*size(im,2) 2]);   % // reshape into 2-column
dist = pdist2(clusters, ab);                   % // compute distances
[~, idx] = min(dist);                          % // find minimizer for each pixel
idx = reshape(idx, size(im,1), size(im,2));    % // reshape result
```

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, you can replace the third line by

```
dist = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@minus, clusters, permute(ab, [3 2 1])).^2, 2));
```

This gives squared distance instead of distance, but for the purposes of minimizing it doesn't matter.