# Find if sum of any row is equal to sum of any column with SUM, ANY, SIZE

Tags: matlab

Tutor gave me an assignment, to check in a 2D matrix if there are any rows which their sum equals to any sum of columns. Allowed to use only `**1 loop**` and only `sum`,`any`,`size`.

```
a = [2 3 4; 5 5 2; 1 3 3; 1 1 1]; --- % Just an example %

rows = size(a,1);
cols = size(a,2);
x = [rows, cols];
tA = a'; i = 1;
RowSum = zeros(rows,1)';
ColSum = zeros(1,cols);

while (i<=max(x))

    if (size(a,1)>=i)
        RowSum(i) = sum(a(i,:));
    end
    if (size(tA,1)>=i)
        ColSum(i) = sum(tA(i,:));
    end
  i=i+1;

end
```

I know it could be a bit messy, but it gave me the job. Now I don't know how to check if there are any matching values in `RowSum` and `ColSum`. (can't use `intersect`); Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you should ask assignment questions on SO.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton By saying "tutor" I mean by my friend (I'm not a student). I just got to a point where I have no idea how to keep progressing from here.

Comment: Two hints:  you don't need a loop to sum the columns and rows (see [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)), and you should read the [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) documentation for the comparison portion.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I understand, I know how can use `sum(A,1)` for columns sum and `sum(A,2)` for rows sum. I can't figure how to use `any` if my matrix is not `NxN`..

Comment: @DanielWatson `any` also accepts a logical vector and produces a logical scalar (`true` if any are `true`; `false` otherwise).  Therefore, `any` can say whether a vector contains an element that matches a scalar: `tf = any(v==s)`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin thanks! managed to use the `any` with `for` loop. Is it possible to do it without a loop?

Comment: @DanielWatson: That's the one loop you are allowed to use, you have to get rid of all other loops.

Comment: @DanielWatson Luis Mendo's answer is the no-loop solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion of the solution and code

You could employ this **three-steps process** and implement the solution with **`sum`**, **`size`** and **`any`** and **`without using any loop`**!!

The steps to be followed for such an implementation could be classified into three steps -

- Get the sum of the input matrix along rows and columns.
- Calculate the distance matrix between all elements of sum along rows against sum along columns.
  The is essentially the most important of these steps and you would have otherwise required at least one loop or `bsxfun` (for internal replication) to perform this. 
  Now, the distance matrix calculation here is performed with matrix-multiplication and is a simplified case of [**this solution to `Speed-efficient classification in Matlab`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26994722/3293881).
- For all distance matrix elements, see if there's any element that is zero.

The code to realize the above steps would look something like this -

```
%// Get the sum of rows and columns into column vectors - A and B respectively
A = sum(M,2)
B = sum(M,1)' %//'

%// Calculate the distance matrix between A and B
nA = size(A,1);
nB = size(B,1);

A_ext(nA,3) = 0;
A_ext(:,1) = 1;
A_ext(:,2) = -2*A;
A_ext(:,3) = A.^2;

B_ext(nB,3) = 0;
B_ext(:,3) = 1;
B_ext(:,1) = B.^2;
B_ext(:,2) = B;

distmat = A_ext * B_ext.'; %//'

%// For all distance matrix values check if any is zero for the final output
out = any(distmat(:)==0)
```

### Sample run and verification

```
>> M (Sample input matrix)
M =
     2    14     3
     5     6     7
     1     5     5
     3     1     2
```

As can be seen that the sum along the third row is `11`, which is the same as the sum along the first column. Thus, in the distance matrix, at least one element must be `zero`.

```
>> A (Sum along rows)
A =
    19
    18
    11
     6
>> B (Sum along columns)
B =
    11
    26
    17
>> distmat (distance matrix between A and B)
distmat =
    64    49     4
    49    64     1
     0   225    36
    25   400   121
```

As estimated earlier, there is one zero at `(3,1)` and thus, the final output of `any(distmat(:)==0)`would be `1`, which is the expected final result.

Comment: Super!! Great thinking :)

Comment: After trying to understand your solution, could you please explain how does the distance matrix works? (what do the values represent, except for the matrix multiplication). [Why did u multiply -2*A?]

Comment: @DanielWatson The link listed in the solution should clear out those questions. Here [it is linked again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994722/3293881). Under `Vectorized Variations`, look for Varation #1 and set `dim` to `1`. So, you need to look at this solution as a special case of that linked solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've done:

```
ColSum = sum(a,1);
RowSum = sum(a,2)';
r = 0;
for i=1:length(ColSum)
    if (any(RowSum==ColSum(i)))
        r = 1;
    end
end
disp(r);
```

Now trying to think how do to it without the loop..

Comment: Any way to do this entire thing without the loop and only with the functions above?

Comment: Only with the functions above and no loops?  I lean toward no.

Comment: Also, you can exit the `for`-loop using the [`break`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) command since you're only looking for the existence of a match and not the total number of matches.

Comment: @TroyHaskin My friend says that it is possible :/ I'll post here when I have the solution..

Comment: @TroyHaskin Well I almost gave up, until I figured one way to do it without loop and with those three functions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27636657/3293881).

Comment: @DanielWatson I would be really interested in seeing what your "friend" had, to solve this without loop and with those three functions only, so please do post that as well.

Answer (score 2):

After you solve it with one loop, `sum`, `any`, `size`, I suggest you read up on [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and find a no-loop, one-line solution with `bsxfun`, `sum`, `any` (hover the mouse to check):

> `any(any(bsxfun(@eq, sum(a,1), sum(a,2))))`

Comment: Cool, thanks. I guess that's not the function I'm allowed to use though, cuz I didn't learn about it yet. Good to know though!

Comment: I figured a way to do the `bsxfun(@eq` by calculating the distance matrix and checking if any of its element is zero. So, this was quite interesting for me. Then, I ran some benchmarks between these two, but didn't see any improvement for the distance matrix based solution over `bsxfun(@eq`, but I thought this was an interesting alternative, just for fun maybe :)

Comment: @Divakar So you managed to do it without loops and with only those three functions! Well done!

Comment: @LuisMendo Yup! Basically that `bsxfun(@eq` translates to `pdist2()==0`, which you might have used before. Not efficient, but a fun alternative :)

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I thought about `pdist2`, but it wasn't allowed. Now I remember you have used that matrix multiplication instead of `pdist2` before