# Finding neuron hits on self-organizing map programmatically

Tags: matlab, neural-network, som

I've been using Matlab's toolbox for self-organizing maps, namely the `newsom` and related family of functions. I'm applying SOM clustering to a large set of documents, and I have used the `plotsomhits(net, features)` to visualize how many patterns/documents are assigned to each neuron. However, I cannot seem to find any functions in the toolbox that retrieve those hits in a data structure instead of just visualizing them.

Now I know that I can find the hits myself, picking the neuron that maximizes the negative distance metric for each pattern, in a simple `for` loop:

```
 nweights = net.IW{1}; % retrieve weights
 mx = -Inf; winner = 1;
 for i = 1:length(nweights)
     distance = negdist(nweights(i, :), pattern);
     if distance > mx % update index of winner 
        mx = distance;
        winner = i;
     end
 end
```

However it seems very odd to me that there is no available function in the SOM toolbox, given that a function for visualizing such results exists.

Does anyone know about this? 
Also, is there a faster method to find the neuron each pattern is 'assigned' to than the one I am describing above?

Comment: What are the typical sizes of the various variables used? Any minimal sample data to work with?

Comment: Feature dimensions are 8296x1, and I have a set of 500 documents (== 500 features). The SOM size is 10x10.

Comment: `negdist` seems to use some sort of distance calculations. On that I could suggest the matrix-multiplication based techniques, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23911671/3293881) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994722/3293881).

Comment: @Divakar thank you, those are very interesting methods.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of hits, you have to use the neural net (`net`) to get the outputs (`y`) from all of your inputs (`X`):

`y = net(X);`

Then, the "hits" for each neuron can be found by simply:

`numhits = sum(y,2);`

In regards to your question about "finding the neuron that is associated with each pattern": perhaps you are over thinking it? It seems that you could simply do:

`y = net(pattern)
neuronNumber = find(y)`

I hope this makes sense. If I am incorrect here, please provide some clarification and I will adjust my answer.