# Speed-efficient classification for complex vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, nested-loops, pdist

I am trying to optimize this piece of code and get rid of the nested loop implemented. I am finding difficulties in applying a matrix to pdist function

For example, 1+j // -1+j // -1+j // -1-j are the initial points and i am trying to detect 0.5+0.7j to with point it belong by min distance approach .
any help is appreciated

```
function result = minDisDetector( newPoints, InitialPoints)
result = [];
for i=1:length(newPoints)
    minDistance = Inf;
    for j=1:length(InitialPoints)

        X = [real(newPoints(i)) imag(newPoints(i));real(InitialPoints(j)) imag(InitialPoints(j))];
        d = pdist(X,'euclidean');

        if d < minDistance
            minDistance = d;
            index = j;
        end
    end
    result = [result; InitialPoints(index)]; 
end     
end
```

Comment: What are the sizes of `InitialPoints` and `newPoints`? Min distance between any 2 points in each set?

Comment: You could get rid of one loop with vectorization: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/47487

Comment: I got a better approach, but it depends on the dimensions of the points.

Comment: The points are complex

Comment: InitialPoints size is either one --   4 , 8 ,16 , 64                                                            newpoints size is big enough

Comment: Are we talking about 1D,2D,3D,4D points here? Are points from each set stored in `InitialPoints` and `newPoints`? It'd be better if you clarified your question with an example of what the variables looked like.

Comment: 1+j // -1+j // -1+j // -1-j are the initial points    and i am trying to detect 0.5+0.7j to with point it belong by min distance approach .

Comment: Are they always imaginary? Re and Im representing each axis?

Comment: Yes they are always .

Comment: @ousamakanawati Let me know if that works for you. If not, comment on my answer and let me know if there are any issues :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use efficient euclidean distance calculation as listed in [**`Speed-efficient classification in Matlab`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994330/speed-efficient-classification-in-matlab/26994722#26994722) for a **`vectorized solution`** -

```
%// Setup the input vectors of real and imaginary into Mx2 & Nx2 arrays
A = [real(InitialPoints) imag(InitialPoints)];
Bt = [real(newPoints).' ; imag(newPoints).'];

%// Calculate squared euclidean distances. This is one of the vectorized
%// variations of performing efficient euclidean distance calculation using 
%// matrix multiplication linked earlier in this post.
dists = [A.^2 ones(size(A)) -2*A ]*[ones(size(Bt)) ; Bt.^2 ; Bt];

%// Find min index for each Bt & extract corresponding elements from InitialPoints
[~,min_idx] = min(dists,[],1);
result_vectorized = InitialPoints(min_idx);
```

---

**Quick runtime tests with `newPoints` as `400 x 1` & `InitialPoints` as `1000 x 1`:**

```
-------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.299187 seconds.
-------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.000263 seconds.
```

Comment: Appears correct and is blazing fast! +1 Perhaps you can include a bit of what each operation does?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you do `[real(newPoints).' ; imag(newPoints).'];` instead of `[real(newPoints) imag(newPoints)]';`?

Comment: @krisdestruction Think it would be the same. Added few comments, but for more info, I think the link must be the actual reference, as it has lots of details needed to really explain the working behind it.

Comment: I just thought about it quickly and it made sense. I was originally wondering why you didn't need `sqrt`, but then I remembered that `min( sqrt )` => `min`! The explanation for the OP, but that works too.

Comment: @krisdestruction Exactly, basically its the squared distances.

Comment: @ousamakanawati If this was the best solution that worked for you, don't forget to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. However you do need my [cartprod.m function](http://pastebin.com/pLW9LbF3) to generate a cartesian product.

First generate random complex data for each variable.

```
newPoints = exp(i * pi * rand(4,1));
InitialPoints = exp(i * pi * rand(100,1));
```

Generate the cartesian product of `newPoints` and `InitialPoints` using `cartprod`.

```
C = cartprod(newPoints,InitialPoints);
```

The difference of column 1 and column 2 is the distance in complex numbers. Then `abs` will find the magnitude of the distance.

```
A = abs( C(:,1) - C(:,2) );
```

Since the cartesian product is generated so that it permutates `newPoints` variables first like this:

```
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 4     1
 1     2
 2     2
 ...
```

We need to `reshape` it and get the minimum using `min` to find the minimum distance. We need the transpose to find the min for each `newPoints`. Otherwise without the transpose, we will get the min for each `InitialPoints`.

```
[m,i] = min( reshape( D, length(newPoints) , [] )' );
```

`m` gives you the min, while `i` gives you the indices. If you need to get the minimum `initialPoints`, just use:

```
result = initialPoints( mod(b-1,length(initialPoints) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to eliminate the nested loop by introducing element-wise operations using the euclidean norm for calculating the distance as shown below.

```
    result = zeros(1,length(newPoints)); % initialize result vector
    for i=1:length(newPoints)
        dist = abs(newPoints(i)-InitialPoints); %calculate distances
        [value, index] =  min(dist);
        result(i) = InitialPoints(index);
    end
```

Comment: This solution is essentially @brodroll's reference. My reference uses 1 `cellfun` loop to generate the cartesian product and doesn't use any explicit loop. Additionally if I'm not mistaken, `abs` already calculates magnitude, meaning `^`, `sqrt`, and `sum` aren't actually needed in your solution.

Comment: Which reminds me, I need to add a reshape to my code :3

Comment: @krisdestruction Thank you, I didn't knew that `abs` returned the modulus of a complex number. Probably not the fastest solution, but I do think that this implementation is simple and concise.

Comment: Concise would be Divakar's answer