# Vector operations using Gpu in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm writing a Matlab code that needs to calculate distances of vectors and I execute

```
X = norm(A(:,i)-B(:,j));
%do something with X
%loop over i and j
```

quite often. It is a relatively small computation so it is not really suitable for parfor, so I thought the best idea would be to implement it with the gpu functions.

I found that pagefun and arrayfun do something like what I want, but they execute element-wise operations and not on vectors.

So my question is, is there a more clever way of calculating norms without for loops? Or if I actually need to use gpu, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: a norm of something is 4 matematical operations, it shoudl be fast. If they are A LOT try `gpuarray` as you mentioned.

Comment: Please put example code with the loop into your question, my feeling is that `pdist2` or `bsxfun` solves this very fast on a CPU if vectorize it.

Comment: I execute this millions of times, so it becomes slow. The "code" is basically some simple operations trying to find which point in high-dimensional space is closer to the other. According to profile viewer this is the slowest part

Comment: pdist2(A',B','euclidean','Smallest',k) is the fastest solution so far (on cpu), but it doesnt run on gpu. Any suggestions?
Also I am testing this on a toy dataset which is much smaller than my real one, so I am not sure if it is really faster.

Comment: See [`this solution : Approach #3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31308903/3293881). It's based on matrix-mul, which must be very fast on a GPU (memory permitting).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the norm between all the elements of A and B, the fastest way is probably this:

```
N = 1000; % number of elements
dim = 3; % number of dimensions
A = rand(dim,N, 'gpuArray');
B = rand(dim,1,N, 'gpuArray');
C = sqrt(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@minus, A, B).^2))); % C(i,j) norm
```

I get the execution time of 0.16 seconds on CPU and 0.13 seconds on the GPU.

Comment: this code works, but pdist2 is faster; any suggestion of faster code?