# find all indices of multiple value pairs in a matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, indices

Suppose I have a matrix A, containing possible value pairs and a matrix B, containing all value pairs:

```
    A = [1,1;2,2;3,3];
    B = [1,1;3,4;2,2;1,1];
```

I would like to create a matrix C that contains all pairs that are allowed by A (i.e. C = [1,1;2,2;1,1]).

Using C = ismember(A,B,'rows') will only show the first occurence of 1,1, but I need both.

Currently I use a for-loop to create C, which looks like:

```
    TFtot = false(size(B(:,1,1),1);
    for i = 1:size(a(:,1),1)
        TF1 = A(i,1) == B(:,1) & A(i,2) = B(:,2);
        TFtot = TF1 | TFtot;
    end

    C = B(TFtot,:);
```

I would like to create a faster approach, because this loop currently greatly slows down the algorithm.

Comment: `TFTot` will either be `0` or `1` depending on whether or not you have found **any** match in `B` using any row from `A`.  Your code will only select out the first row of `B` if at all.  You should probably make `TFtot` an array that keeps track of whether we have found the particular row in `B` in `A`.  Also, `A(i,2) = B(:,2)` should really be `A(i,2) == B(:,2)`.... but comparing a scalar to a vector will yield true *unless all* values in the comparison result are 0. You should use `any/all` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.  You just need to swap `B` and `A`, then use this output to index into `B`:

```
L = ismember(B, A, 'rows');
C = B(L,:);
```

How `ismember` works in this particular case is that it outputs a `logical` vector that has the same number of rows as `B` where the i<sup>th</sup> value in `B` tells you whether we have found this i<sup>th</sup> row somewhere in `A` (`logical` 1) or if we haven't found this row (`logical` 0).

You want to select out those entries in `B` that are seen in `A`, and so you simply use the output of `ismember` to slice into `B` to extract out the affected rows, and grab all of the columns.

We get for `C`:

```
>> C

C =

     1     1
     2     2
     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you! This exaclty fits my needs :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
C = B(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, B, permute(A, [3 2 1])),3),2),:);
```

Or you could use [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics Toolbox):

```
B(any(~pdist2(A,B),1),:);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`matrix-multiplication based euclidean distance calculations`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26994722/3293881) -

```
Bt = B.';  %//'
[m,n] = size(A);
dists = [A.^2 ones(size(A)) -2*A ]*[ones(size(Bt)) ; Bt.^2 ; Bt];
C = B(any(dists==0,1),:);
```