# Subsequent time-series matching

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, time-series, euclidean-distance

I've been stuck with subsequent matching of time-series in MATLAB (I'm new to it).

I have two time-series: A (of length a) and B (of length b). Assume that a is much larger than b. The task is to find the closest window from A to B (according to Euclidian metric).

In order to do that I construct additional matrix C that stores all subsequences of the length b from A and then use pdist2(C, B). Obviously it works slowly and requires too much memory.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. How to obtain C without loops (actually to reshape A)?
2. What are the common ways to solve this problem? (preferably in MATLAB but other environments are also possible)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you could try

```
tmp = repmat(A,1,b);
C = reshape([tmp zeros(1,b)],a,b);
C = C(1:(a-b+1),:);
```

Besides, `pdist2` is very slow in comparison to this very nice solution: [Efficiently compute pairwise squared Euclidean distance in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911670/efficiently-compute-pairwise-squared-euclidean-distance-in-matlab/23911671#23911671)

Comment: Thanks! I've got significant acceleration reshaping time-series and I will try to avoid pdist2. P.S. It must be tmp instead of B in the second row

Comment: This is a nice approach to create all shifted versions of a signal, but it took me a while to get the idea with the added zeros - maybe you could add some explanation?

Comment: Zeros are needed to get the proper dimensions of a matrix after reshaping. As I use pdist2, I need all the signals to be the same length. Actually they are cut anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For part 2 of your question, a typical way of comparing sequences is through [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW). You should almost certainly be able to Google for a Matlab implementation.

The basic version of the DTW algorithm has complexity O(nm), but approximate versions that typically have comparable performance have complexity closer to O(max(n, m)).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't been familiar with DTW but I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) ([`xcorr`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html)) as an approach to this problem. On how cross-correlation and euclidian distance are related, refer for instance to [the introduction of this article](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.html). It is not invariant to scaling in time or amplitude and may be sensitive to noise, but the question does not imply any such distortions.

An advantage of cross-correlation is its efficient implementation in the transform domain. Unfortunately I have only an old Matlab version without `pdist2` at hands, so I can not time it. But consider

```
%// Parameters
a = 1e4;
b = 1e2;
noise = 0.1;

%// Create sample signals with some distortion
A = rand(1, a);
Offset_actual = 321
B = A(Offset_actual + [1:b]) + noise*rand(1, b);

%// Computation
CC = xcorr(A, B);
[m, i] = max(CC);
Offset_estimated = i - a
plot(CC)
```

which should recover `Offset_estimated == Offset_actual`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's a bit overwhelming for me but I will try this approach.