# Using Caffe to classify "hand-crafted" image features

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, deep-learning, caffe

Does it make any sense to perform feature extraction on images using, e.g., OpenCV, then use Caffe for classification of those features?

I am asking this as opposed to the traditional way of passing the images directly to Caffe, and letting Caffe do the extraction and classification procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does make sense, but it may not be the first thing you want to try:
If you have already extracted hand-crafted features that are suitable for your domain, there is a good chance you'll get satisfactory results by using an easier-to-use machine learning tool (e.g. libsvm).

Caffe can be used in many different ways with your features. If they are low-level features (e.g. Histogram of Gradients), then several convolutional layers may be able to extract the appropriate mid-level features for your problem. You may also use caffe as an alternative non-linear classifier (instead of SVM). You have the freedom to try (too) many things, but my advice is to first try a machine learning method with a smaller meta-parameter space, especially if you're new to neural nets and caffe.

Answer (score 2):

Caffe is a tool for training and evaluating deep neural networks. It is quite a versatile tool allowing for both deep convolutional nets as well as other architectures.
Of course it can be used to process pre-computed image features.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28411646/1714410) also applicable here ;)