# Which toolbox can perform MIMO system identification in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, identification

I would like to perform system identification on a MIMO (multiple input, multiple output) system in Matlab. Are there any functions or toolboxes available to do this?

Comment: Why is this question too broad? I would like to know if there is any toolbox that can help me.

Comment: There is the system identification toolbox in Matlab https://www.mathworks.com/products/sysid.html There is also some freely available code for MATLAB and Python here: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelIdentification I'm using Python Gekko that also has an interface here: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Seeq

Answer (score 10):

> Is it possible to perform system identification on a MIMO (multiple input, multiple output) system in Matlab?

Yes.

Comment: Simplest answer I have ever seen, I guess you will have to elaborate on this.

Comment: @GameOfThrows OP doesn't ask for more. It's definitely possible to do MIMO in MATLAB, so the answer is yes.

Comment: well...This user...I am lost for words...

Comment: Can't argue with that, Adriaan. But anyway, the question is *so* broad that any other answer would be utterly incomplete.

Comment: @hbaderts does that also mean that Adriaan's answer is complete?;)

Comment: @GameOfThrows Adriaan was [following precedent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404292/thinning-handwritten-characters-in-matlab/28411646#28411646) :).