# Retaining and identifying elements in an array which satisfy a threshold in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, threshold

I have a matrix (about 342 by 342) denoted by `C_{ij}` and I want to identify all indices i,j which satisfy the condition `C_{ij}` > rho where rho is some fixed value. I am using MATLAB

For example, if I have the matrix `C_{ij}` as:

```
C = 1     0.7    0.8
    0.7   1      0.5
    0.8   0.5    1
```

And rho = 0.6 then the indices which satisfy the condition `C_{ij}` > 0.6 are i,j = 1,2 as `C_{11}=C_{22}=1` and `C_{12}=C_{21}=0.7`
But note that i,j=3 does not satisfy this condition since although `C_{13}=C_{31}=0.8`, `C_{23}=C_{32}=0.5`

I am not sure how/the best way to do this is in MATLAB?

Comment: `[k,l]=find(C>rho);`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's the criterion to include or not include a given pair `i,j` in the result? Is `C` always symmetric?

Comment: @LuisMendo I read the criterion as "needs to be larger than rho", and whether `C` is symmetric or not isn't really relevant, besides that if it is symmetric you might use `[rowt,colt,~] =  find(triu(C)>rho]; row = [rowt;colt]; col = [colt;rowt]`. I'm not sure whether that's faster than simply using a logical on the full matrix.

Comment: @Adriaan You're probnably right, as you have 4 upvotes by now :-) But I don't see how `C(2,3)` influences the decision for `i=3`, `j=3` according to the OP

Comment: Upvotes are by no means a way of telling whether someone's correct or not [e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725121/which-toolbox-can-perform-mimo-system-identification-in-matlab/34725330#34725330) ;). I think the OP's unsure about the row/column structure and whether operators work along those.

Comment: @Adriaan Hm... you were jealous of Ray's three-letter answer, weren't you? :-)

Comment: Are the top-left/bottom-right corners of the square submatrix always on the diagonal, or could you have a submatrix bounded by `C(2,1),C(3,2)`?

Answer (score 7):

```
C = rand(342,342);
rho = 0.6;
res = C(C>rho); %// contains all values that are above the threshold
[row,col,val] = find(res); %// returns the indices.
```

`row` would contain your i, `col` your j, but I'd caution against [using `i` or `j` as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). `val` contains the corresponding value, but you can omit that for freeing RAM, as you can use `C(row,col)` as well to get the values.

If your matrix is symmetric you can use that:

```
[rowt,colt,val] = find(triu(C)>rho); %// find only in the upper triangle
row = [rowt;colt]; %// flip rows and columns to obtain all results
col = [colt;rowt]; %// flip rows and columns to obtain all results
```

For your edit:

```
IdxR = find(diff(unique(rows))==1,1,'first');
IdxC = find(diff(unique(columns))==1,1,'first');
Result = C(1:IdxR,1:IdxC);
```

Comment: "`and I want to identify all indices i,j which satisfy the condition`"

Comment: @AndrasDeak "retaining and identifying" according to his title, now it does both

Comment: @Adriaan @AndrasDeak Yes the matrix is always symmetric. although I would prefer a method which doesn't assume this. Perhaps I didn't explain my criterion correctly. Using the matrix in my original question as an example, that first code would identify `k` and `l` to be 1, 2 and 3. However, that would include the element `C(2,3)` and `C(3,2)` which are both < rho. Hopefully that clear things up a little. It's rather hard to explain this without LaTeX

Comment: @Ansh this code would not include those elements, as they are not above the threshold.

Comment: @Ansh have you tried the above (general) solution on a specific matrix? What makes you think that it will return indices that correspond to values which violate the comparison?

Comment: @Adriaan ah I see the confusion now (partly because I've confused myself). I should specify that since C(2,3) and indeed C(3,2) do not satisfy the condition I want only the following block to be retained from the original matrix:         [1 , 0.7 ; 0.7 , 1] - i.e. for this case the C(1,1), C(2,2), C(1,2) and C(2,1) elements i.e. in this particular case the upper left 2 by 2 block.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes I did indeed try that solution for the matrix given in my question. Hopefully my comment above clarifies things better.

Comment: @Ansh Adriaan's answer *doesn't* give you `C(3,2)`, but `C(3,1)` it does. Is *that* your problem? Then your not after individual elements, but full rectangular blocks which abide by the condition. Is that what you want? Submatrices given by `C(indexvector1,indexvector2)`? If yes, you need to really rephrase your question, as it's a much more difficult problem, and needs a different solution.

Comment: @Ansh Clarifications should be edited into your question. If your question is not self-contained and clear, it should be closed.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - the question has now been edited to make it clearer as to what it is I exactly want. Does this help?

Comment: @Ansh almost: square or rectangular submatrix? Can the result be non-square?

Comment: @AndrasDeak No the submatrix must be square given the way I want the threshold condition to work