# Given two sets of vectors, how do I find the closest vector in the second set for each vector in the first set?

Tags: matlab, vector, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

Given: Two sets `{S1, S2}` of vectors of dimension `D`. `S1` is represented by a `N*D` matrix and accordingly is `S2` represented by a `M*D` matrix.

I am looking for an elegant way to get for every vector `s1` in `S1` the nearest neighbour `s2` in `S2` and the according distance.

A simple approach would of course be to have two for loops and get

```
dist = norm(s1 - s2);
```

However, there must be a more elegant and efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup.  With the mighty power of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), with a side of [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), and a dash of [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  This would be the first part, where you calculate the pair-wise distances between a point in `S1` and another point in `S2`:

```
out = reshape(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, S1, permute(S2, [3 2 1])).^2, 2)), size(S1,1), size(S2,1));
```

The last thing you need now is to determine the closest vector in `S2` to each of `S1`.  That can be done using [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html):

```
[dist,ind] = min(out, [], 2);
```

`dist` would contain the smallest distance between a point in `S1` with a point in `S2`, and `ind` would tell you which point that was.

---

This code looks very intimidating, but let's break it up into pieces.

1. `permute(S2, [3 2 1])`:  This takes the matrix `S2`, which is a `M x D` matrix and shuffles the dimensions so that it becomes a `1 x D x M` matrix.... now why would we want to do that?  Let's move onto the next part and it'll make more sense.
2. `bsxfun(@minus, S1, ...)`: `bsxfun` stands for **B**inary **S**ingleton E**X**pansion **FUN**ction.  What `bsxfun` does is that if you have two inputs where either or both inputs has a singleton dimension, or if either of both inputs has only one dimension which has value of 1, each input is replicated in their singleton dimensions to match the size of the other input, and then an element-wise operation is applied to these inputs together to produce your output.  In this case, I want to subtract these two newly formed inputs together.

   As such, given that `S1` is `N x D`... or technically, this is `N x D x 1`, and given that `S2` is `M x D`, which I permuted so that it becomes `1 x D x M`, we will create a new matrix that is `N x D x M` long.  The first input will duplicate itself as a 3D matrix where each slice is equal to `S1` and that is `N x D`.  `S2` is now a 3D matrix, but it is represented in such a way where each row in the original matrix is a slice in the 3D matrix where each slice consists of just a single row.  This gets duplicated for `N` rows.

   We now apply the `@minus` operation, and the effect of this is that for each output slice `i` in this new matrix, this gives you the component wise difference between the point `i` in `S2` with all of the other points in `S1`.  For example, for slice #1, row #1 gives you the component wise differences between point #1 in `S2` and point #1 in `S1`.  Row #2 gives you the component wise differences between point #1 in `S2` and point #2 `S1`, and so on.
3. `sum((...).^2, 2)`: We want to find the Euclidean distance between one point and another point, so we sum these distances squared over each column independently.  This results in a new 3D matrix where each slice contains `N` values where there are `N` distances for each of the `M` points.  For example, the first slice will give you the distances from point #1 in `S2` with all of the other points in `S1`.
4. `out = reshape(..., size(S1,1), size(S2,1));`: We now reshape this so that it becomes a `M x N` matrix so that each row and column pair of `(i,j)` gives you the distances between points `i` in `S1` and `j` in `S2`, thus completing the calculations.
5. Doing `[dist,ind] = min(out, [], 2);` determines the smallest distance between a point in `S1` with the other points in `S2`.  `dist` will give you the smallest distances while `ind` will tell you **which vector it is**.  Therefore, for each element in `dist`, it gives you the smallest distance between a point `i` in `S1` and one of `S2`, and `ind` tells you which vector that was that belonged to `S2`.

---

We can verify that this gives us correct results by using your proposed approach of looping through each pair of points and calculating the norm.  Let's create `S1` and `S2`:

```
S1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];
S2 = [-1 -1 -1; 0 9 8];
```

More neatly displayed:

```
>> S1

S1 =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12

>> S2

S2 =

    -1    -1    -1
     0     9     8
```

Using the loop approach, we have this code:

```
out = zeros(size(S1,1), size(S2,1));
for ii = 1 : size(S1,1)
    for jj = 1 :size(S2,1) 
        out(ii,jj) = norm(S1(ii,:) - S2(jj,:));
    end
end
```

We get this matrix:

```
>> out

out =

    5.3852    8.6603
   10.4881    6.0000
   15.6525    7.1414
   20.8327   10.9545
```

Similarly, if we ran the code I wrote, we also get:

```
>> out = reshape(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, S1, permute(S2, [3 2 1])).^2, 2)), size(S1,1), size(S2,1))

out =

    5.3852    8.6603
   10.4881    6.0000
   15.6525    7.1414
   20.8327   10.9545
```

To complete the process, let's find the smallest distances and the corresponding vectors:

```
>> [dist,ind] = min(out, [], 2);
>> dist

dist =

    5.3852
    6.0000
    7.1414
   10.9545

>> ind

ind =

     1
     2
     2
     2
```

Therefore, for the first vector in `S1`, the closest vector to this in `S2` was first one, with a distance of 5.3852.  Similarly, the second vector of `S1`, the closest vector in `S2` was the second one, with a distance of 6.  You can repeat this for the other values and see that it's correct.

Comment: This doesn't get out of calculating N*M norms, correct? It just gets rid of the for loop?

Comment: @MatthewGunn No it doesn't, but it's faster.

Comment: What I was writing before was all wrong. Let me think about it for a sec if there's a nice way to do it.

Comment: @MatthewGunn no problem at all.  I'm interested to see how you can do this with matrix multiplication.  I began that way, but couldn't see a way to do it, which is why I pulled out `bsxfun`.

Comment: Some way of iterating, either for loop or bsxfun is the way to go to get the vector difference for each combination. 

Sorry for my earlier mindfart.

Comment: @MatthewGunn no problem at all.  I was actually excited when you came out with your answer because I didn't see how to do it with matrix multiplication... but it was your reasoning that ultimately led me to give up and I had to use `bsxfun`.  Either way, it was great to see your attempt.

Comment: @Simon I forgot that you wanted to find the closest vectors.  I just added that in as an edit.

Comment: @Simon so did what I write help you? Consider accepting one of our answers if you no longer need help. Good luck!

Comment: @MatthewGunn - I forgot about this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911670/efficiently-compute-pairwise-squared-euclidean-distance-in-matlab - This is how you'd do it with matrix multiplication, but you need to write a loop to set things up first.  It's certainly faster!

Answer (score 5):

How about in one line?

```
[dist, ind] = min(pdist2(S2,S1));
```

`ind` is the index of the nearest vector in `S2` for each vector in `S1`, and `dist` gives the corresponding minimum distance.

Borrowing [@rayryeng's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33660668/2586922),

```
S1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];
S2 = [-1 -1 -1; 0 9 8];
```

the results are

```
dist =
   5.385164807134504   6.000000000000000   7.141428428542850  10.954451150103322
ind =
    1     2     2     2
```

Comment: Ghe, is it also faster than the might `bsxfun`?

Comment: @Adriaan _Nothing_ is faster than `bsxfun` :-P Except for [matrix multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23911670/2586922)

Comment: Very nice.  I forgot to use `pdist2`, but I liked how I came up with `bsxfun/permute` all by myseslf!