# Calculating distance of all the points storing in one array with all other points of second array

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to calulate the distance of all points stored in an array which size is <17642065x2 double> with the all points of other array which size is  <273839x2 double>. The points stored in both array are in form of:

A = 
 341   45
 456   32
 987   10
 4003  332
 ...   ...
 ...   ...
 .... ....

B = 
 344   67
 786   90
 1234   47
 3456  222
 ...   ...
 ...   ...
 .... ....

I have to calculate distance for all points. For example the algorithm calculates the distnace between (341,45) and (344,67), then (341,45) and (780,90), then (341,45) and (1234,47), then (341,45) and (3456,222) then (456 32) and (344,67) and so on. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your ideas? Btw: are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: Did you look at [`pdits2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Matlab's builtin `pdist2` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html):

```
d = pdist2(A,B);
```

Comment: Shouldn't one reshape matrices A and B two make them two-dimensional first? ```A2d = reshape( A, 2, length(A)/2 )``` ...

Comment: Yes, but in the question he wrote `<17642065x2 double>` etc., so I assumed it is already a 2d array

Comment: I have used this command but  Matlab gives error "Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options".

Comment: That's because the answer is too large to be held in your computer's RAM. You should break your arrays to smaller sub-arrays and treat each one separately.

Comment: I have solved this error. when I execute command of memory, MATAB gives:                                                                                              Maximum possible array:                8840 MB (9.270e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:       8840 MB (9.270e+09 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:                 1809 MB (1.897e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):                 4018 MB (4.213e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.           which shows that I have a memory of 6931MB but command pdist2 still gives  same error.

Comment: It might be that some intermediate calculation needs more memory, or that the amount of contiguous memory (which Matlab needs in order to allocate space for arrays) is smaller. Anyway, there's not much you can do unless you install more RAM. The simplest thing is to break down the arrays as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of matheburg on this question(
[Efficiently compute pairwise squared Euclidean distance in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911670/efficiently-compute-pairwise-squared-euclidean-distance-in-matlab)) answers your question. It is even faster than `pdist2`, which can be useful when you have to do this computation on multiple arrays.

Comment: I have implemented the code proposed by matheburg but Matlab gives me error which is " Error using  * MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. At least one input must be scalar.To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead. Give me suggestion how to resolve this problem

Comment: I tried the following code based on part of your matrices and had no problems (the output is a 3x3 matrix) : d=2;numA=3;

numB=3:
A=[341 45;456 32;987 10];
B=[344 67; 786 90; 1234 47];
helpA=zeros(numA,3*d);
helpB=zeros(numA,3*d);
for idx = 1:d
    helpA(:,3*idx-2:3*idx) = [ones(numA,1), -2*A(:,idx), A(:,idx).^2 ];
    helpB(:,3*idx-2:3*idx) = [B(:,idx).^2 ,    B(:,idx), ones(numB,1)];
end
distMat = helpA * helpB'; The output is distMat=[
         493      200050      797453;
       13769      112264      605509;
      416698       46801       62378]

Comment: Did u run this code on the above mentioned size of matrix?? as when I run this code on that matrix it  gives me error of CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: also can you please explain working of code? I'll be really thankful to you

Comment: can you tell me your email ID so that I would be able to share my data with you.