# Is MATLAB's bsxfun the best? Python's numpy.einsum?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I have a very large multiply and sum operation that I need to implement as efficiently as possible. The best method I've found so far is `bsxfun` in MATLAB, where I formulate the problem as:

```
L = 10000;
x = rand(4,1,L+1);
A_k = rand(4,4,L);
tic
for k = 2:L
    i = 2:k;
    x(:,1,k+1) = x(:,1,k+1)+sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,A_k(:,:,2:k),x(:,1,k+1-i)),2),3);
end
toc
```

Note that `L` will be larger in practice. Is there a faster method? It's strange that I need to first add the singleton dimension to `x` and then `sum` over it, but I can't get it to work otherwise.

It's still much faster than any other method I've tried, but not enough for our application. I've heard rumors that the Python function `numpy.einsum` may be more efficient, but I wanted to ask here first before I consider porting my code.

I'm using MATLAB R2017b.

Comment: Many times a for loop is faster than bsxfun. But you seems to try it already...?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is faster than `bsxfun`, but this doesn't seem to easily lend itself to that

Comment: @LuisMendo I've considered transforming the problem into a sparse matrix multiplication but it's a bit daunting... You think it would be faster?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @horchler MATLAB R2017b

Comment: If an operation with `bsxfun` / implicit broadcasting can be directly transformed into matrix product, [yes, it's faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23911671/2586922). But here the transformation could take too much time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe both of your summations can be removed, but I only removed the easier one for the time being. The summation over the second dimension is trivial, since it only affects the `A_k` array:

```
B_k = sum(A_k,2);
for k = 2:L
    i = 2:k;
    x(:,1,k+1) = x(:,1,k+1) + sum(bsxfun(@times,B_k(:,1,2:k),x(:,1,k+1-i)),3);
end
```

With this single change the runtime is reduced from ~8 seconds to ~2.5 seconds on my laptop.

The second summation could also be removed, by transforming times+sum into a matrix-vector product. It needs some singleton fiddling to get the dimensions right, but if you define an auxiliary array that is `B_k` with the second dimension reversed, you can generate the remaining sum as ~`x*C_k` with this auxiliary array `C_k`, give or take a few calls to `reshape`.

---

So after a closer look I realized that my original assessment was overly optimistic: you have multiplications in both dimensions in your remaining term, so it's not a simple matrix product. Anyway, we can rewrite that term to be the diagonal of a matrix product. This implies that we're computing a bunch of unnecessary matrix elements, but this still seems to be slightly faster than the `bsxfun` approach, and we can get rid of your pesky singleton dimension too:

```
L = 10000;
x = rand(4,L+1);
A_k = rand(4,4,L);
B_k = squeeze(sum(A_k,2)).';

tic
for k = 2:L
    ii = 1:k-1;
    x(:,k+1) = x(:,k+1) + diag(x(:,ii)*B_k(k+1-ii,:));
end
toc
```

This runs in ~2.2 seconds on my laptop, somewhat faster than the ~2.5 seconds obtained previously.

Comment: Wow! This is also about 4 times faster on my laptop. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex just make sure it's correct, I only took a cursory glance and didn't check rigorously due to all the `NaN`s and `Inf`s. I think I could get rid of your second sum which would further improve performance, I just don't have the time right now :)

Comment: @Alex so I removed the second sum too, it's only slightly faster as the previous version, but it might scale better for larger problems.

Comment: Faster, but I get very different outputs for `x` as `L` grows (seeding `rand` the same each time).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Great! I'm getting the same outputs for each when I seed with the same `rand` (at least up to the `Inf`'s). Looks like I should brush up on my linear algebra... :)

Comment: @horchler Are you sure? I forgot to clear x between tests the first time I compared but it seems good now.

Comment: There are definitely differences, but they appear to be due to the numerics (e.g., different order of operations) as they are on the order of `eps(max(x(:)))`.

Comment: Thanks, @horchler, for the heads-up. Hopefully it's fine considering Alex' comments, but I'll check on the numbers later to be sure.

Comment: @Alex also, considering the python implementation: `numpy.dot` is what's _really_ fast (it uses low-level compiled routines and utilizes multiple cores by default). While I love `einsum` due to its expressive power, it gets slower for multiple (more than 2) input arguments (although this would not be such a case).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Do you think `numpy.dot` will be any faster than MATLAB? I'd like to benchmark it but I'm not sure how to formulate the problem as a dot product.

Comment: @Alex sorry, you're right, I was distracted by my original dotty notions. Well, you _can_ use `.dot` the same way I used matrix multiplication in my second example, and then you can grab the `numpy.diag` of the resulting array in the same way. I can't say if that or `einsum` or broadcasted multiplication+sum would be faster, you should time them all to see. One important difference to MATLAB is that while MATLAB is column-major, numpy is row-major, so vectorization is fast along leading dimensions in MATLAB but it's fast along trailing dimensions in numpy.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ah I see. I was hoping we might get rid of the extra calculations that we discard with `diag`. And good to know about the leading dimensions!

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using an new version of Matlab you might try broadcasting / [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) instead of `bsxfun`:

```
x(:,1,k+1) = x(:,1,k+1)+sum(sum(A_k(:,:,2:k).*x(:,1,k-1:-1:1),3),2);
```

I also changed the order of summation and removed the `i` variable for further improvement. On my machine, and with Matlab R2017b, this was about 25% faster for `L = 10000`.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Absolutely. Half of the 25% improvement is due to changing the order of summation as well.

Comment: It appears the implicit version is ever so slightly faster than `bsxfun`.

Comment: @horchler Oh, I hadn't noticed that part